# Field-level security using Grails 2.x with Spring Security plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

Is it possible to implement field-level security using the Spring Security Core plugin in Grails?

We are currently using method-level security with the [@Secured](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#securedAnnotations) annotation, but there are some users that should only be able to update some of the fields of an entity. We can use the [security taglib](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#securityTagLib) to hide the fields that shouldn't be accessed, but this is only a client-side restriction (and therefore can be easily circumvented).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Spring Security Core plugin for Grails doesn't have any support for this, directly. However, there is nothing stopping you from writing your own security around binding.

For example, in your controller:

```
package com.example
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
class PersonController {
  ...
  def update() {
    Person personInstance = Person.get(params.id)
    if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') {
      bindData(personInstance, params) // exclude nothing 
    } else {
      bindData(personInstance, params, [exclude: ['someSensitiveProperty', 'anotherProp']]) 
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

In theory you could even encapsulate this binding logic inside the domain class itself in binding method of your choice (e.g. `personInstance.bindDataWithSecurity(params)`)

Comment: I didn't know this was possible! Thank you!

Comment: No worries. If enough people want I can look at making a plugin that would allow you configure this at a domain class level and wire up binders that are dynamically generated and wired into the application.